# From CTAN to TeX Live and MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, texlive, ctan

A few months ago (before the release of TL2013) I uploaded a script to [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexindent).

What are the next steps (if any) that need to be taken to get the script or package part of the TeX Live and MiKTeX distributions?

Comment: Contact the maintainers?

Comment: I was waiting for you for this ;-). So we can expect latexindent in miktex soon. :-)

Comment: Almost all the time, if the license is acceptable, TL will just pick up a package by routine.  You could ask about it on the TL mailing list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For (La)TeX packages, there is really not much to do from the author's point of view: uploads are picked up by the TeX Live team and Christian Schenk, and are then added to TeX Live and MiKTeX, respectively (license-allowing). The TeX Live team provide an [overview of their requirements](http://tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html): that I know of there are no MiKTeX guidelines, but following the TeX Live ones can't hurt in this case either. Assuming you've already uploaded to CTAN, key points are:

- Pick a 'free' license, and unless you have a strong reason pick an existing one
- Include the source for your documentation as well as the documentation itself
- Don't use `@` in file names

The TeX Live guidelines apply to scripts as well as packages, with the additional advice that Perl or Lua are the 'preferred' languages as they are bundled with TeX Live. MiKTeX doesn't have Perl built-in, so a Perl script in MiKTeX will require some action by the end user. That shouldn't prevent it going in to MiKTeX, though. There's also advice on naming: don't create any new conflicts!

Comment: TL has the additional constraint that the package (software) must be useful for *free* software. Free support packages for commercial software (e.g. fonts) are excluded.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Ye, I know but I didn't want to just reproduce the entire page :-)

Comment: great, thanks Joseph :) it sounds like I have already followed most of those steps, so I assume it's just a matter of time? I uploaded my script quite a while ago, so have been somewhat surprised that it hasn't been picked up yet...

Comment: @cmhughes I would assume so, but you might want to e-mail the TeX Live list to check. MiKTeX is a one-man operation, so there you'd need to check directly with Christian S.