# Does TexShop include the exscale, lmodern, and pdf/standalone pkgs,& Ghostscript 9.15+?

Tags: installing, texshop, wolfram-mathematica

I'm interested in installing [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html), a LaTeX typesetting package for Mathematica.

The installation instructions say I need the following. Are they included with the latest TexShop distribution?

> A TeX system that includes pdflatex with the `standalone`, `exscale`
>   and `lmodern` packages. Both TeX Live and MiKTeX should work.
>   Ghostscript 9.15 or later. On OS X, MacTeX 2015 includes a compatible
>   version of Ghostscript. If you use an older TeX distribution on OS X,
>   get a recent Ghostscript from Richard Koch’s page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! TeXshop is just an editor, not a distribution. The distribution itself for Mac is MacTeX 2016 (latest).

Answer (score 4):

TeXShop is an editor, not a TeX Distribution. For the Mac you should download MacTeX

- [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/downloading.html)

It's usually best to install the full version.  TeXShop is also installed with MacTeX along with TeX Live Utility, which is a useful tool for updating your distribution.

After installing you should typically use it to update packages to the more recent versions.

See:

- [TeX Live Utility, don't know how to start it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254375/2693)

Answer (score 1):

TeXShop is a front end for a TeX distribution. The recommended TeX Distribution for the Mac is TeX Live and is installed by the MacTeX package (which also installs Ghostscript (9.20)) and several GUI applications. Please go to <http://www.tug.org/mactex/> for more information.

Comment: It is not a front end for a TeX distribution. It is just an editor.