# Removal Failed - Removing TexLive Package result in Error

Tags: pdftex, texlive-2017

I want to uninstall some of the unused TeXLive Packages with the TexLive Utility.
Unfortunately while removing them, i still got the error:

> "Removal Failed"

The alert says:

> The removal process appears to have failed. Would you like to show the
>   log now or ignore this warining?

Anybody a clue what to do ?

Am I able to delete the packages manually ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Do you use the newest version?  Related: [TeX Live Utility, don't know how to start it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/254378/124842).

Comment: @Bobyandbob The newest version of TexLive Utility ? Yes, I do. Version 1.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in most cases for to dependencies. If you have a collection installed that depends on the package, a simple remove will not work and one needs to force the removal. I'm not sure whether the TLU GUI supports forced removals, on the command line you would need to do `tlmgr remove --force <pkg>`

Comment: Does this command also removes the packages which are dependent   on the actual package ?

Comment: That is unclear a question. Packages that depends on <pkg> are not removed, packages onto which <pkg> depends are removed if <pkg> is a collection (afair).

Comment: The package _multirow_ also distributes the package _bigdelim_ and _bigstrut_. In order to use _bigdelim_ I have to install _multirow_. But when calling the command `tlmgr remove --force <pkg>`, does this command also removes _bigdelim_ and _bigstrut_ ?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about TeX Live packages which correspond to CTAN packages, not to single .sty files.