# How and where to install a .cls in a minimal TexLive distribution (MacOsX)?

Tags: installing, document-classes, mac

I have a minimum LaTeX live installation which I don't remember how it got installed. I think it was a dependency of some other program and it got automatically installed.

Nevertheless, the content of my `/usr/local/texlive/2022basic/bin/universal-darwin` is the following

```
afm2tfm     fmtutil-sys lualatex    mktexmf     simpdftex   xdvi
bibtex      fmtutil-user    luaotfload-tool mktexpk     synctex     xdvi-xaw
dvilualatex gftodvi     luatex      mktextfm    teckit_compile  xdvipdfmx
dviluatex   gftopk      lwarpmk     mpost       tex     xelatex
dvipdfm     gftype      makeindex   mptopdf     texhash     xelatex-dev
dvipdfmx    inimf       man     pdfatfi     texlua      xelatex-unsafe
dvipdft     initex      mf      pdfetex     texluac     xetex
dvips       kpseaccess  mf-nowin    pdflatex    thumbpdf    xetex-unsafe
dvitomp     kpsereadlink    mfplain     pdftex      tlmgr
ebb     kpsestat    mft     pktogf      tlshell
etex        kpsewhich   mkindex     pktype      updmap
extractbb   latex       mktexfmt    r-mpost     updmap-sys
fmtutil     luahbtex    mktexlsr    rungs       updmap-user
```

whereas I don't have a `texmf` folder in `/Users/ubaldot/Library/`, nor I can see any LaTeX related environmental variable set.

However, if I run `which pdflatex` from the command line I get `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex`

**Problem:** I am in need to install `standalone.cls` file, due to an external program (*manimCE*) that require it but I don't know how to install such a .cls file within my current setup.

I could install a whole LaTeX distribution and use some package manager for solving my problem but I would rather avoid that.
I am just wondering if I can install `standalone.cls` within my current setup and if so, how.

Let me know if more info are needed so I can edit this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have installed the BasicTeX version of MacTeX, you simply need to install extra packages or classes manually. You can do this using the TeX Live Utility (which may have been installed with BasicTeX) which is a GUI wrapper for `tlmgr` or you can use `tlmgr` directly from the command line.

For details on using TeX Live Utility see:

- [TeX Live Utility, don't know how to start it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254375/2693)

To install things from the command line using `tlmgr` you can do the following:

```
sudo tlmgr install standalone
```

It will ask for your password, and then install it in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed TeX Live via the MacTeX installer package you should put personal packages in or in sub-folders of ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex. The texmf/tex/latex folder hierarchy in ~/Library must be created by you since the MacTeX installer package doesn’t touch your HOME folder.

Comment: But `standalone` isn't a personal class, it's part of the standard distribution. So assuming the OP has installed BasicTeX from the MacTeX distribution they should use TeX LIve Utility or `tlmgr` to install the class in the main `texmf` tree.

Comment: Sigh… I didn’t look closely enough. The answer is for personal packages.